# How can I test two different test groups concurrently?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

I'm trying concurrently run my tests except for tests that include login.

I've tried to separate tests into two groups (with login and without login). These two groups run in parallel. Tests without login are running concurrently with each other, but tests with login run one after each other. The problem is that runner only runs tests without logins twice. I saw .serial feature discussion in https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/116 and I think it would help a lot in this situation.

```js
const createTestCafe = require('testcafe');
const config = require('./config');
const testArrayBuilder = require('./Tests/helpers/testArrayBuilder');
let testSteps = require('./Tests/helpers/testSteps');

let testcafe;

const store = process['argv'][2],
      name = process['argv'][3],
      env = process['argv'][4];

const testsFile = require(`./Tests/${store}/tests.json`);
const output = 'logs/test-results-' + store + '-' + env + '-' + name + '.json';

createTestCafe('localhost', 0)
    .then(tc => {
        testcafe = tc;

        const tests = getTests();

        const runner = testcafe.createRunner();

        if (name !== 'all') {
            runner.filter(testName => {
                return testName === name;
            });
        }

        runner.reporter(['spec', {
            name: 'json-custom',
            output: output
        }]);

        return Promise.all(tests.map(obj => {
            if(obj.login === true) {
                //Don't change number value for this one,
                //because login tests won't run properly.
                return runTests(runner, obj.tests, 1);
            } else{
                return runTests(runner, obj.tests, 1);
            }
        }));
    })
    .then(() => {
        testSteps.mergeWithReporter(output);
        testcafe.close();
    });

const runTests = (runner, tests, windows) => {
    return runner
        .src(tests)
        .browsers(config.browsers)
        .concurrency(windows)
        .screenshots('logs/screenshots/', true)
        .run({
            skipJsErrors: true,
            quarantineMode: true,
            selectorTimeout: 20000,
            assertionTimeout: 20000,
            pageLoadTimeout: 20000,
            speed: 0.5,
            stopOnFirstFail: false
        });
}

const getTests = () => {
    const testsWithoutLogin = testArrayBuilder(testsFile[env], false);

    switch (store) {
        case 'shop1': 
            const testsWithLogin = testArrayBuilder(testsFile[env], true);
            return [{login: true ,tests: testsWithLogin}, {login: false, tests: testsWithoutLogin}];

        case 'shop2': 
            return [{login: false ,tests: testsWithoutLogin}];
    }
}
```

Note that if I write createRunner() part in runTests(), reporter is overwritten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you use the same runner for parallel test execution in the `Promise.race` function. I would recommend you use different runners for both your test sets.

Comment: So I should create different runners and then merge their reporters? Because I need test info to be stored in one reporter and I thought there would be a way to avoid that.

Comment: Of course, I don't know your task in detail, but I think it's better to have a separate report for each runner and then merge them. If you do not want to merge them, you can redirect your console output to a file using the command: `node index.js > report.txt`. However, in this case your report will be mixed by outputs of both runners. Please refer to the gist to see what I mean https://gist.github.com/AlexKamaev/a7e9f320a6e8b902f598554f26bd17b7

Comment: Thanks for help. I ended up merging both custom reports together.